# specifying mysqli bind_param types

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

what are the pros and cons of specifying mysqli bind_param types `i,d,s,b`?

I store a UNIX timestamp in a db column with data type INT. In my prepared statement I set it to `bind_param('s',$timestamp);` and it stores the value without any problems. So what impact did it make that I used `s` instead of `i` during `bind_param`?

Comment: Did you read the manual? => http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah and I didnt find my answer. maybe you could point it out cause I'm stupid.

Comment: Don't put yourself down like that. It's the stupid ones that don't ask questions ;-)

Comment: It's same as the difference between doing `SET row = 123` and `SET row = '123'`.  MySQL will convert the value into the correct type for you.  So doing `bind_param('i',$timestamp);` would save MySQL the conversion operation.

Comment: In a nutshell, if your column is an `INT` and you place place quotes around an integer `WHERE column='1'` instead of `WHERE column=1` that could make a difference. Same thing goes for `d` and `b` for mathematical equations and storing data/images into a table. By not choosing `b` you'll end up with some unexpected surprises.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: MySQL will convert between strings and ints, but there are probably scenarios where that could cause an issue.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I agree. When it comes to mostly string values, I use `s`. If it starts giving me a hard time, I'll resort to what it should most likely be. 99% of the time, `s` works just as good for most data types; excluding blob.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Fred-ii- ok that cleared things up. I gotta go cause I need to change a lot of . . stuff :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It influences how MySQL will see the query/value. Take this query:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?)
```

If you bind the parameter as int:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $bar);
```

Then the query will be about equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (42)
```

However, if you bind as string:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $bar);
```

The query will be about equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('42')
```

In many cases MySQL doesn't particularly care whether you send it a string or an int and will simply cast the value to the appropriate type on the fly, just as PHP does most of the time. However, in some circumstances and with some types you may get an unexpected conversion, which is why you should bind the value as the type that you want it as and not leave it up to MySQL's casting rules.

Comment: Any php documentation link?